# (E_ERROR) Too few arguments to function Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profile::__construct(), 0 passed

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to relate a profile model to the existing user model using the relationship belongs to and hasOne and I am getting that error.

here is my Profile.php

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
     <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profile;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'username', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

In my terminals i can get the user through the profile but cannot get the profile using user. here is the error

```
$user->profile
TypeError: Too few arguments to function Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/Profile::__construct(), 0 passed in /Users/macair13/freeCodeGram/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php on line 720 and exactly 1 expected.
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, replace the `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profile;` line on top of your *User.php* file with `use App\Profile;` instead.

This is happening as you've mistakenly included the wrong class on top of your `User.php` file. When Laravel is trying to load the relationship, it attempts to construct a `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profile` object instead of constructing your intended model.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below in your user model

```
public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'foreign_key');
    }
```

I am not sure why you have used `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profile` in your user model. When your relationship is building it is using that `Profile` and not your Profile Model. You have to use the Profile Model namespace while defining the relationship.